# How to make blinking imageview in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I would like to make imageView with some background blinking. I will set frequency and it will have to blink. I think that `blinking = View.VISIBLE/View.GONE` or I'm wrong? As I understand I can use kotlin Coroutines for solving this task because ordinary recursion won't help me. So, in my activity class I have added such method:

```
private fun showAlertDialog() {
        val dialogue = Dialog(this)
        var scope = GlobalScope
        dialogue.setContentView(R.layout.alert_dialogue)

        dialogue.window?.apply {
            attributes =
                window!!.attributes.apply { width = LinearLayoutCompat.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT }
        }

        val img = dialogue.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.rgb_main_item)

        scope.launch {
            while(true) {
                runOnUiThread {
                    img.visibility = if (img.visibility == View.GONE) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
                }


                delay(140)
            }
        }

        img.setOnClickListener {
            scope = GlobalScope
        }

        dialogue.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)

        dialogue.window!!.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
        dialogue.show()

    }
```

as you can see in the code above - it creates dialogue with single image and transparent background. In general it works as I mentioned above, but sometimes I don't know what happens and I see small delay between two blinks and then frequency is damaged due to this delay and after some moments it blinks good again. I think that I did smth wrong with Coroutine function call or in another place.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting `visibility` to `VISIBLE/GONE`, better to use `alpha` property to get the most realistic effect

```
 val blinkAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(img, View.ALPHA, 0F,1F)
 blinkAnim.repeatCount = ObjectAnimator.INFINITE
 blinkAnim.repeatMode = ObjectAnimator.REVERSE
 blinkAnim.duration = 140
 blinkAnim.start()
```

Comment: but this code also will be used inside coroutine?

Comment: No need it can be invoked directly on main thread, animators use schedulers to delay and stuff

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution, using a countdown timer :

```
const val BLINKING_DURATION = 5000L
const val BLINKING_PERIOD = 500L

val img = dialogue.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.rgb_main_item)

var blinkerOn = false

val timer = object : CountDownTimer(BLINKING_DURATION, BLINKING_PERIOD) {
    
    override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
        when (blinkerOn) {
            true -> img.visibility = View.GONE
            false -> img.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }
        blinkerOn = !blinkerOn
    }
    
    override fun onFinish() {
        /* action when time is over */
        }
    }
}.start()
```